# Brain.js import not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I must be missing a basic setup thing, but I cannot get the [examples on brainJS working](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js).

The examples mention importing a module and then creating a neural net:

```
import brain from 'brain.js';
const lstm = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();
```

But, when copy>pasting the tutorials, or trying any other path to the brain.js folder, I get this error, with **brain** underlined in the terminal:

> import **brain** from 'node_modules/brain.js/index.js'
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

My directory structure

```
app.js
- node_modules (folder)
--- brain.js (folder)
------index.js
```

It seems that there is only a "brain.js" folder but not a file. I have tried importing with:

```
 import brain from 'node_modules/brain.js/index.js';
 import brain from 'node_modules/brain.js/';
 import brain from './brain.js/index.js';
```

etc. etc.

Comment: If you get a syntax error on the *import* that's a separate issue. Normally you'd just write `import brain from 'brain.js'` if it's any sort of normal NodeJS project. An unexpected identifier is a *syntax* error, which is different than it not being found.

Comment: Brain.js import not found... sounds like my morning!  BRB, fetching caffeine.

Comment: Coffee.js import also not found :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using **Node.js**?  If so, I believe `import` isn't supported yet.  If you are using Node, you should use:

```
const brain = require('brain.js');
```

I tried this and it works fine.  Hope this helps.

Comment: If they're *just* using NodeJS (e.g., not using babel-node), and *not* using `--experimental-modules`, that's true.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why the official files DO use the `import` statement... Node has `import` support but that only works with `.mjs` files it seems.

Comment: @DaveNewton It does seem that the official project uses babel. The "how to use" tutorial skips over this little detail :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as brain from 'brain.js';
```

---

Q: *Why does this not work?*

```
import brain from 'brain.js';
```

A: Javascript's ES6 import statement is looking for an ES6 module with a `default` export.  Brain doesn't use this export, it makes little sense since there are more than one neural network type.  Here is an example using default export:

```
export default {};
```

---

Q: *Can imports be used with older javascript libraries?*

A: Absolutely. As stated in the answer: `import * as library from 'library-name';`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the browser use this code in order to allow the browser to use the browser friendly version of the source code Brain.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/BrainJS/brain.js/45ce6ffc/browser.js"></script>
```